# if $x\ne 0$, is at least one of $\{x, \cos\;x\}$ transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: transcendental-numbers

it seems at least superficially plausible that for real $x \ne 0$ then at least one of $\{x, \cos\;x\}$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$. has this assertion been proved to be true or false?

Comment: The http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem implies that if $x$ is algebraic, then $\cos(x)$ is transcendental.

Comment: thank you Prahlad - that reference leads to some interesting reading

Answer (score 4):

Prahlad Vaidyanathan's comment answers the question:

> The [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) implies that if $x$ is algebraic, then $\cos(x)$ is transcendental.

So your conjecture is correct.