# is the unique solution of $\cos t = t$ a transcendental number?

Tags: trigonometry, transcendental-numbers

let $\alpha$ be the unique fixed point of $\cos:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [-1,1]$

for any $t \in \mathbb{R} \setminus\{0\}$ if $t$ is algebraic then $\cos t$ is transcendental. thus if $\alpha$ were algebraic it must also be transcendental, a contradiction, since $\cos\alpha = \alpha$. hence $\alpha$ is transcendental.

QUESTION is this argument valid?

NOTE re the stated assumption, in answer to [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621039/if-x-ne-0-is-at-least-one-of-x-cos-x-transcendental-over-mathbbq)  Prahlad Vaidyanathan pointed me to  [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) re the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: It could use a reference for the cited fact.

Comment: Writing \cos, with a backslash, rather than just cos, not only prevents italicization, but also provides proper spacing in things like $a\cos b$.  I deleted the manually added spacing and put in the backslash.

Comment: thank you Michael, it has been irksome adding manual spacing.  I suppose this applies to other trig functions and log. I will check this. I've only learned basic mathjax by frequently consulting the excellent MSE tutorial sheet, and by looking at other peoples' equations so any fine-tuning is much appreciated

Comment: @GEdgar point taken. I'm rather new to this, hence the question. this has been puzzling me for some while, so it is remarkable to see that the solution is so simple, (if the reasoning here is is OK).

Comment: @DavidHolden : many functions work this way, e.g., max, min, exp, sup, inf, lim, log, ...  If in doubt, try putting a backslash before it.

Comment: Yes, the reasoning is OK.

Comment: thank you Robert. it is amusing that once I had learned of the Lindemann-Weierstrass type of result, I was confused for a time by the thought that it would not apply because $\alpha$ and $\cos \alpha$ are equal. it took a while to twig that it is this very fact that lines up a simple reduction ad absurdum

Comment: Wonderful question and wonderful answer!

Comment: As a side note, the solution to this equation is known as the [Dottie number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sifting throuht the material of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem one concludes that

$\alpha \ne 0$ and algebraic $\implies e^{\alpha}$ transcendental

Assume that $\cos t = t$ is algebraic. Then $it$ is also algebraic and $\ne 0$, and so is $s=e^{it}$, as the solution of the equation $\frac{s+1/s}{2} = t$, contradiction with the above for $\alpha = i t$.

Yes, the argument of the OP is valid.

Comment: @Wojowu: Agreed, done.